# Trouble debugging my Angular project in VSCodium

Tags: linux, vscodium

I'm encountering difficulties when attempting to debug my Angular project in VSCodium. Whenever I try to initiate debugging, I receive the following error message: "Cannot connect to the target at localhost:4200: Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost:4200: Could not find any debuggable target."

Here are the specifics of my setup and the problems I'm facing:

Development Environment:

I'm using Zorin OS as my operating system.
VSCodium is my chosen IDE for Angular development.

Problem Details:

Despite properly configuring the launch.json file with the correct URL and browser executable, I'm still unable to debug my Angular project in VSCodium.
I've verified that my Angular development server is running correctly with the ng serve command.
Has anyone else encountered similar issues when debugging Angular projects in VSCodium on Zorin OS? Are there any specific configurations I may be overlooking or any workarounds I can try to resolve this issue?